# Ruby and Python sending data over serial behaving differently

Tags: python, ruby, lcd

I am currently trying to make a Ruby library for an LCD. I have written a small amount of Python code that sends an image, and I derived it from the example code. This code works. It successfully updates the LCD screen with a bitmap image provided.

```
import serial
import io
import sys
import os
import time
import re

ser1 = serial.Serial()              #initialize serial connection
ser1.baudrate = 115200              #set baud rate
ser1.port = '/dev/ttyACM0'          #set port
print ser1.port                     #print out port for verification
ser1.open()                         #start serial connection

bmp1 = open('image.bmp', 'rb')      #open bitmap file for sending
Data1 = bmp1.read()                 #store data in variable
bmp1.close()                        #close bitmap file
ser1.write(Data1)                   #send data over serial to the LCD
```

However, when I converted this code to Ruby, running it would not display anything on the LCD. Running it again also wouldn't display anything. Running it a third time, however, would cause the LCD to be filled with three copies of the image, overlapping each other. If I cleared the screen and ran it again, the final result of the overlapped images would not always be the same as the previous time.

The following is my Ruby code:

```
require 'serialport'

port = "/dev/ttyACM0"

baud = 115200

puts "Connecting to LCD on port #{port}, with baud #{baud}"
lcd = SerialPort.new(port, baud)

bmp = File.open("image.bmp", "rb")
data = bmp.read
bmp.close
puts "Sending data..."

lcd.write(data)
```

I can't seem to figure out why they would behave this differently, or how to make the Ruby code work as expected. I have also tried adding `lcd.flush` to the end of the file, but it still doesn't display it on the first run of the program.

Comment: did you try to `flush` the data?

Comment: @UriAgassi I've been experimenting with it for the last day and I tried that, to no avail. I added `lcd.flush()` to the end of my file, and it still doesn't send it right away

Comment: the lcd display don't return anything when you send information? try to read the return, if there are one, and see the differences. it's very probably Ruby Serial implementation have different details in it's own serial, like buffer handling

Comment: you've tried the lcd.flush_output() from the serial gem?

Comment: @VictorH.Panisa I hadn't until now, but it has the same effect for me. The LCD doesn't send anything back. I tried writing the output of reading the bitmaps to a file and comparing them ruby vs python, and they were exactly the same, according to `diff`. It is definitely a difference in the serial library